# Unable to create new lists in New Twitter

Tags: twitter, list

I switched to New Twitter and now I could not create new Lists. It shows the message "List Created!" every time I create one but the List drop down never shows it. I'd only 1 List built long time ago and hence have not exceeded the quota of 20 Lists / user. Any thoughts why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are not filling out the description.
Place some information in the description section and it should work.

Comment: On the form under the description box it states "Under 100 characters, optional" so I don't think you have to fill it out.

Comment: I just tested this.  If I left Description blank, I saw `List created`, but no list.  If I then created it again, this time filling in a short description, the list was created just fine.  Perhaps they're not sure what optional means or maybe the 100 character limit is the optional part?

Comment: It is a bug with the new interface. I tried it myself. Continuously creating a new list without filling out a description leads to a notification message but no new list.